# Stuck on Android Tutorial

Tags: android, facebook

I've been following the Android Tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

I reached step 6.4, build and run the project.  My app prompts me to login, logs in with no error messages, and then just displays a page with the text "Hello World!"  The tutorial mentions that at this point I should be getting prompted with a dialog about permissions, but this isn't happening.  I can't find code anywhere to display the Hello World text, so that's bizzarre too.  I have no error messages.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you already have in place please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it after reading the keystore troubleshooting. Originally, I didn't use the default "android" for the keystore password. Once I did that, my app started correctly.

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
Enter keystore password:  android
```

Comment: However, fixing the keystore solution only worked once. On subsequent runs, I went back to a flash followed up by the "Hello World" screen. At least LogCat still shows "Completed" with @brody's code.

Answer (score 0):

Put in some Log.d to see what's happening. Most likely it's because your app isn't requesting for permissions and basic info is free to be accessed.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Completed!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Facebook Error!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error!")
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG,"User Canceled");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your app doesn't need permissions, so it's not asking for them. For "Hello world" text check out the main.xml file in res/layout and the string.xml in res/values.